# How to stop any decimals rounding up in visual basics 2017?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm doing this thing from the visual basics 2017 book where a table can hold 8 guests max and everything works fine except for when I have guest numbers that go up by factors of 4 (except factors of 8). 1 guest gives me 1 table but when I put 4 guest it gives me 2 and stays that way until I put 8 guests.

```
If dblGuest Mod dblTable = 0 Then
            dblTotal = dblGuest / dblTable
        ElseIf dblGuest Mod dbltable <> 0 Then
            dblTotal = dblGuest / 8 + 1
        End If
```

Comment: You should not be using `ElseIf` with a condition that is the exact opposite of the one in the `If` block. You should just be using `Else`. If you check a condition and it is not true then you know it's false, so there's no point checking whether the opposite condition is true because you already know for a fact that it is.

Comment: Based on your Hungarian prefixes, all your variable are type `Double`? Why would that be? They are all whole numbers, aren't they? Why are they not type `Integer`? Can you really have a fractional number of guests or a fractional number of tabloes? I doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're using `Mod`, I would assume that you want integer division, rather than floating-point division. In that case, use `\`, which is the integer division operator, rather than `/`.

Personally, I'd be doing it something like this:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Const guestCountPerTable As Integer = 8

        For guestCount = 0 To 40
            Console.WriteLine($"{guestCount} guest(s) requires {GetTableCount(guestCount, guestCountPerTable)} table(s)")
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetTableCount(guestCount As Integer, guestCountPerTable As Integer) As Integer
        Dim tableCount = guestCount \ guestCountPerTable

        If guestCount Mod guestCountPerTable <> 0 Then
            tableCount += 1
        End If

        Return tableCount
    End Function

End Module
```

You could also use the `Math.DivRem` method:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Const guestCountPerTable As Integer = 8

        For guestCount = 0 To 40
            Console.WriteLine($"{guestCount} guest(s) requires {GetTableCount(guestCount, guestCountPerTable)} table(s)")
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetTableCount(guestCount As Integer, guestCountPerTable As Integer) As Integer
        Dim remainder As Integer
        Dim tableCount = Math.DivRem(guestCount, guestCountPerTable, remainder)

        If remainder <> 0 Then
            tableCount += 1
        End If

        Return tableCount
    End Function

End Module
```